# Homology of $\mathbb{R}\setminus A_+$.

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, homotopy-theory

Let $A$ be the unit circle in the $xy$ plane in $3$-dimensional real space and let $A_+$ be a semicircle. I have to compute the homology of $\mathbb{R}^3\setminus A_+$. I was thinking that $\mathbb{R}^3\setminus A_+$ is homotopically equivalent to $\mathbb{R}^3\setminus \{(1,0,0)\}$  which can than be proved to be homeomorphic to $S^2$. However, I have trouble finding a retraction $g:\mathbb{R}^3\setminus \{(1,0,0)\}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^3\setminus A_+$  to construct the equivalence, since homotopy equivalence is not stable under subtractions, i.e. if $A,B\subset X$, $A$ homotopically equivalent to $B$ it does not follow that $X\setminus A$ homotopically equivalent to $X\setminus B$.

Comment: It's not really clear what you mean by $A_+$. Does it include the interior of the semicircle, or just the boundary? If the latter, does it include the diameter of the circle that "chops it in half", or not?

Comment: just the boundary. It is just something like $x^2+y^2=1, x\geq 0$.

Comment: There is no such retraction $g$. One way to see this is to look at the composite $I \hookrightarrow \mathbb R^3 \backslash \{(1,0,0)\} \overset{g}{\to} \mathbb R ^3 \backslash A_+ \hookrightarrow \mathbb R^3$ where $I$ is some curve that intersects the semicircle $A_+$ at a single point $p$. Every point on $I$ other than $p$ must be fixed by this map; by continuity, $p$ must also be fixed. But since $p$ doesn't lie in $\mathbb R^3 \backslash A_+$, this is a contradiction. What is true is that the two spaces are homotopy equivalent.